# Instant Search on Material UI AutoComplete Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Forced to press enter twice on form submission with AutoComplete Material UI component. I want to be able to only select the options once to navigate to another web page.

[Submission Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl3mx.png)

[Component Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kui6e.png)

I attempted to change around the submission handler and the paper/box components, but the problem persists. Once I select an option from the dropdown menu from AutoComplete the user has to hit enter again.

Answer (score 1):

You implement instant search on the **AutoComplete component**, using **useEffect ReactJS**.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

function searchAutocomplete({ option, onSelection }) {
  const [searchTermValue, setSearchTermValue] = useState('');
  const [filteredOptionValue, setFilteredOptionValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredOptionValues(option.filter((option) =>
      option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchTermValue.toLowerCase())
    ));
  }, [searchTermValue, option]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      option={filteredOptionValue}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderInput={(param) => (
        <TextField
          {...param}
          label="Search"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => setSearchTermValue(event.target.value)}
        />
      )}
      onChange={onSelection}
    />
  );
}
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: This isn't the solution that I'm looking for. The Issue is even though I select a value from the filtered options it won't navigate on first click. You have to click enter again